# Where can I get Olympus C-8080 Replacement Parts?

Tags: repair, olympus, lcd

I've had my trusty Olympus C-8080 for some time now, and its still a great camera. But it has been "archived" and is no longer in productions as far as the camera or the parts go. I am no photography buff like I am sure many of those here on this forum are, and I have spent several days on and off over the past month looking for any inkling of ability to find parts for my camera. I can do the work myself, thats not the issue. Its finding the part I need so I can replace the broken with the working.

What I need is an LCD view finder screen, as the one on the camera was damaged and unrepairable. However I can't find any places that sell the parts directly. I know they are "specialty" at this point, seeing as they aren't just available.

But all places I have found and or talked to insist I send them the camera and they will order the part and they will do the work and they will charge me 400+ dollars for it all (from the sounds of it) Which if I am going to drop $400 on repairs then Im just gonna end up throwin down a couple hundred extra for a Canon EOS Rebel or something. Or maybe a Nikon D3200? I dunno. Either way its like I said I like my camera, I don't want to replace it, I'd rather find the screen buy it and replace it myself.

So with that I guess my ultimate question is two fold. One, does anyone know where I can find the screen? I can't find them on eBay. Two. Does anyone know what parts are compatible with the C-8080 from maybe another olympus or aftermarket part company? That I can maybe find one of those and use it instead? Example, is there another Olympus or 10 out there that use the same size/shape LCD for the display, that is still active on the market?

Comment: Unfortunately when point and shoot cameras die, this is what happens. For the majority of them, finding parts can either be very difficult or simply not worth it. Your best bet is buying one broken for a different reason if you _really_ want to salvage it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will almost certainly need the exact screen.  Things like the type and length of the connection for the screen are going to matter, so it is highly unlikely you will find another one that fits unless it is from the same model.  Have you considered just looking for a used Olympus C-8080 that you could salvage the screen yourself (or just use the used one.)  They seem to be available for as low as $118.

Comment: I have toyed with the idea of buying one for salvage, again its one of those things where money is a slight factor.. If I am gonna drop a couple hundred overall (and I know going new is a big leap from just a couple hundred vs new prices) I am just gonna buy new.. if I can find a screen for 50-75$ ill go that route, otherwise Ill end up buying new in the end after saving a few hundred bucks for the cause of buying new.

Comment: @Chris - I doubt you will find someone trying to salvage old point and shoots for parts to sell separately.  You might be able to find someone selling a non-working model on eBay and get lucky for your price range, but it's honestly probably not worth the effort or time it would take to track one down.  There just isn't enough financial reason to buy up old point and shoots since they are more or less disposable tech.

Comment: I also tried searching for the actual part number pulled from [this](http://oss.erdfunkstelle.de/C8080.pdf) exploded view of the camera with no luck.  Didn't appear to be in any other models either.  I think you are pretty much out of luck.

Comment: doh lol, well I thank you for going out of your way to help, and for everything else mentioned. I think your right. May have to opt out of being frugal, opt out of wanting to savor the old over the new

Answer (score 0):

even though it would cost more.. try United Camera.  They seem to be able to repair older cameras

Comment: Can you add a bit more to this? Are they noted for it? Have you used them? This is pretty thin and probably more appropriate as a comment.